# A way to send an alert to downvoters that an edit has been made to the post

Tags: feature-request, voting, down-votes, notifications

Would it be be possible to make something that would alert downvoters of an answer that the post they downvoted has changed?

Comment: Anyone care do comment why they downvoted (the irony is killing me)

Comment: This has been asking frequently on Meta.StackOverflow, the basic gist of it was: if your post is bad, I get to downvote it. More often than not, edits don't change my opinion, so bothering me about it won't do you any good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is already a notification when you downvote that says:

> please consider adding a comment if you think this post can be improved

Doesn't get any more in your face than that, if a user doesn't want to explain him/herself, they most likely won't.

Comment: But they would not know if the post was edited...

Comment: If the post is edited, they have a chance to redact the vote. You should restate your question to ask that they notify the user of the downvote if the post is edited. Not if they just downvoted a post.